# (bash) flock: when to use the -c option?

Tags: bash, flock

Can anyone explain to me why the `-c` option exists in `flock`?

I can't find a good description of how it differs from simply specifying the command(s) to execute after `flock` (apart from its limitation of no arguments to the command).

Comment: -c allows you to pass only single command

Comment: Thanks @BallPython, but that doesn't answer the question. I already know the limitations imposed by `-c`; I'm trying to understand why it exists, why we need it, when we should use it.

Answer (score 3):

`-c` invokes a shell with the command.

Consider this:

```
flock .lock somecommand > myfile
```

Since `>` is interpretted by the current shell and not flock, `myfile` will be truncated before the lock is captured.

You can work around this with `-c`:

```
flock .lock -c 'somecommand > myfile'
```

Now the redirection is performed after the lock is captured. However, it is indeed useless since you could just have invoked a shell yourself:

```
flock .lock sh -c 'somecommand > myfile'
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the `man` page is unclear. It should say "-c passes the following command string to a _new_ shell." And anyway - _which_ shell does it execute? Is it always `sh`?

Comment: It's `$SHELL` with a fallback to `sh`.

Comment: So when `-c` is not used, it must be the current shell that executes the supplied command... How does `flock` manage that?

Comment: @RashaMatt flock still runs the command it just doesn't handle redirections and the like as those are already handled by the time flock runs and sees the arguments specifying the command to run.